# Wordpress custom template for archive

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I am running Wordpress 3+ and am using Advanced Custom Fields plugin.
I have two custom post types - 'Releases' and 'Artists'.

At the moment, both archive pages default to the archive.php template.

I have set up archive-releases.php AND archive-artists.php so I can have different archive templates for my two custom post types.

Any idea why these are defaulting to archive.php and not their specific archive templates?
Can't work out why a custom post type called 'Releases' can't find the archive-releases.php template.

Comment: did you mention while registering custom post `'has_archive' => true`

Comment: yes that has been enabled.

Comment: and what is the structure of your permalinks

Comment: Post name in the form http://site/wordpress/sample-post/

Comment: archive-releases.php in theme root directory should work if your post type is correctly named "releases", and "has_archive" is true. Did you try to hit the permalink save button again?